# jQuery UI Tooltip - Manual close after event.stopImmediatePropagation, no effect?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, event-handling, jquery-events

http://jsfiddle.net/r2nzc/5/

```
var $textInput = $('#textInput');
var items = '.ui-autocomplete li.ui-menu-item a';

$textInput.autocomplete({
  source: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
  minLength: 0,
  open: function(){
    $('body').tooltip({
      items: items,
      content: 'Hello!'
    });
    
    $(items).mouseout(function(event){
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
        $('body').tooltip('close');
    });
  }
}).focus(function(){
    $(this).autocomplete('search', '');
});
```

I am attempting to override jQuery UI's tooltip autoclose functionality. My intent is to able to hover over the tooltip without it closing, but this functionality has not yet been introduced. As such, I am trying to hack it in.

My understanding is that I should be able to call `event.stopImmediatePropagation` to prevent the tooltip from closing after the `mouseleave` event. However, this would leave the tooltip open forever. So, I have need to close the tooltip manually.

If I call 'destroy' on the tooltip, I can force it to instantly close. This seems like an ugly workaround because I do not get the nice fading out of the tooltip.

Unsure how to debug why close doesn't seem to work. Is the tooltip keeping track of its internal state?

Comment: `close()` only works on non-delegated tooltips, and yours are apparently delegated to the `<body>` element. I would suggest subclassing the widget or trying your solution with non-delegated tooltips.

Comment: How could I apply my tooltip in a non-delegated fashion to the jQuery autocomplete elements?

Comment: You would have to apply tooltip widgets to every item in the completion menu (and `destroy()` them when the menu items are replaced or destroyed themselves). I suspect this not to be trivial. Deriving your own tooltip widget might be the better solution here.